# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions on iPhone is very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to load into a scrollView on the iPhone , very big images.
Doing so with the iPad it worked great , but now, when i am trying on the iPhone (4 for example), i can see that things are very **slowly** .

I wonder if its because the size of the image-which should be resized to the screen size.
I am loading the images from web with async lazy load .

removing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` makes it a little bit faster, but than the scroll view is flicks(not scrolls good) .

Is there a better way to resize the huge images ( 1200-1700 pixels) ?

```
 [self downloadImageWithURL:userUrl completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data)
     {
         if (!succeeded)
             return ;

         [self.imageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
          {
              UIImage *image =nil;

              image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

              if (image)
              {
                  //have tried here many scaling factors ,with no results .
                  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, 0.4);
                  [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

                  image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
              }




              [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
               {
               imageView.image=image;
```

Comment: You're drawing into an image context that is the same large size as the image. Wouldn't you be better off drawing it into an context at a more reasonable size?

Comment: you mean to set the size to be the actually final size ?

Comment: Yes. otherwise you're still loading the huge image into memory when displaying it, even though it's showing at a (presumably) much smaller size.

Comment: ok thanks, please see my edit also if you can..

Comment: btw, when i do what you said i don't see the image at all..

Comment: ok forget about the edit, i have checked it out and its due to the very low loading, i have tried to set the size as you suggested to be the image view size, but than i see no image at all

Comment: iPhone 4 is pretty old now and runs ios 7 slowly. You should check performance on more recent units if possible.

Comment: simulation iPhone 5 also the same..i guess something is wrong